# I face problem in ORDER BY when i select multiple data for data-table source in CodeIgniter but i got 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

I want data to be ordered by `eIsPinned` column.

I already tried this:

```php
$this->datatables->order_by('eIsPinned','desc')
```

But I got a 500 (Internal Server Error)

```php
$this->datatables->select('((SELECT CONCAT(vFirstName," ",vLastName) FROM tbl_student WHERE `tbl_student`.`iStudentID` = `tbl_student_kilgoreform`.`iStudentID`)) as vStudentName,IF(((SELECT count(iPinID) as tot FROM tbl_student_pinform WHERE `tbl_student_pinform`.`iStudentID` = `tbl_student_kilgoreform`.`iStudentID` AND iFormID=10 AND iInstructorID='.$iInstructorID.')) > 0,"Yes","No") as **eIsPinned**,enter code herevCourse as vCourse,vLabSection as vLabSection,vSemester as vSemester,iSim1Total as iSim1Total,iSim2Total as iSim2Total,iSim3Total as iSim3Total,iSim4Total as iSim4Total,iTotal as iTotal,iKilgoreFormID as iKilgoreFormID, eLastUpdateBy as eLastUpdateBy,eFormCompleted as eFormCompleted,DATE_FORMAT(dAddedDateTime, "%m/%d/%Y") as dAddedDateTime,iStudentID, iKilgoreFormID as DT_RowId',false);
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.iProgramID',$getInstructorData['iProgramID']);
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.eDeleted','No');
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.iFormID',10);
$this->datatables->order_by('eIsPinned','desc');   // I used this but I got error.
```

Comment: `elsPinned` not `eIsPinned`(if it's not a typo)

Comment: @sauhardnc a column name that would called _is pinned_  so in snake-case `isPinned` and with the `e` that seems to prefix most of the OP columns `eIsPinned` seems legit to me.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
 Yes, I used `e` as a prefix for understanding this column as an enum and `isPinned`  is camelCase for the column name

Answer (score 0):

This solution i found .... 
I used db instead of datatables.

```
$this->datatables->select('((SELECT CONCAT(vFirstName," ",vLastName) FROM tbl_student WHERE `tbl_student`.`iStudentID` = `tbl_student_kilgoreform`.`iStudentID`)) as vStudentName,IF(((SELECT count(iPinID) as tot FROM tbl_student_pinform WHERE `tbl_student_pinform`.`iStudentID` = `tbl_student_kilgoreform`.`iStudentID` AND iFormID=10 AND iInstructorID='.$iInstructorID.')) > 0,"Yes","No") as **eIsPinned**,enter code herevCourse as vCourse,vLabSection as vLabSection,vSemester as vSemester,iSim1Total as iSim1Total,iSim2Total as iSim2Total,iSim3Total as iSim3Total,iSim4Total as iSim4Total,iTotal as iTotal,iKilgoreFormID as iKilgoreFormID, eLastUpdateBy as eLastUpdateBy,eFormCompleted as eFormCompleted,DATE_FORMAT(dAddedDateTime, "%m/%d/%Y") as dAddedDateTime,iStudentID, iKilgoreFormID as DT_RowId',false);
            $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.iProgramID',$getInstructorData['iProgramID']);
            $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.eDeleted','No');
            $this->datatables->where('tbl_student_kilgoreform.iFormID',10);
    $this->db->order_by('eIsPinned','desc');   // This is the solution which I used for that.
```